# python splitting string without cutting words

Tags: python, split

I found some similar questions, but nothing from python.

**The context:**

I have many pdf files (text) which have a table among other texts.
The position and size of the table varies from file to file.
I already tried different libraries but pdftotext was the best until now. tabula didn't work for example.

**Solution until now:**

I use pdftotext to extract all the info as a big string, find the substrings that will always delimit the table and save the table in a variable

Unfortunately, I can't write the whole content of the table, but the first two lines:

```
D  Staph. aureus  Ps. aeruginosa E. coli ATCC Ser.             Asp.           Cand. albicans
a  ATCC 6538,     ATCC 9027, Ps. 8739, Ent.     marcescens     brasiliensis   ATCC 10231,
```

since pdftotext puts a "\n" at the end of each line, I could split the table into each row

My goal here is to separate this string into substrings as columns like this:

```
['Staph. aureus', 'Ps. aeruginosa', 'E. coli ATCC', 'Ser.', 'Asp.', 'Cand. albicans']
```

and this:

```
['ATCC 6538,     ', 'ATCC 9027, Ps. ', '8739, Ent.     ', 'marcescens     ', 'brasiliensis   ', 'ATCC 10231,']
```

The second line was delimited in every 15 characters for example

I realized that the maximum length of a column is 15 characters, so i tried splitting it like this, with n = 15:

```
print([line[i: (i + n)] for i in range(0, len(line), n)])
```

but this is what I get:

```
['Staph. aureus  ', 'Ps. aeruginosa ', 'E. coli ATCC Se', 'r.             ', 'Asp.           ', 'Cand. albicans']
```

the question here is how to cut the string in substrings without cutting the words?
I already realized that if I cut on the position line[i + n], the position line[i+n-1] has to be equal to " " in order to not cut a word.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string into words using `str.split()`. If you do not provide a deliminator it will use spaces by default and return the words of a string. See the official Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: I know, but as you can see on the goal list, some elements have more than one word. Unfortunately the amount of words per column is not always the same.

Answer (score 0):

The data seems to be tab delimited, but with the tabs replaced with spaces.

The only pattern I can spot is multiple spaces between column values.If this is the case your code would break if there was a double space (e.g. typo by the author).

Using the maximum column width is risky. It would break if the columns have short values (e.g. 'one', 'two').

Comment: Yes, I thought I could split in double spaces, but it didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Would this be of help?

```
str = "D  Staph. aureus  Ps. aeruginosa E. coli ATCC Ser.             Asp.           
Cand. albicans"
list = []

for s in str.split():
    if "." in s:
        list.append(s)
    elif list:
        list[-1] = f"{list[-1]} {s}"

print(list)
```

output:

```
['Staph. aureus', 'Ps. aeruginosa', 'E. coli ATCC', 'Ser.', 'Asp.', 'Cand. albicans']
```

This splits the string at whitespace, then goes through the resulting array and starts a new entry in the list if a word contains "." and appends that index in the list with the following words until the next word with "." is encountered.

I can't see a rule that we could apply to all rows, but with these two examples we could do:

```
line1 = "D  Staph. aureus  Ps. aeruginosa E. coli ATCC Ser.             Asp.           Cand. albicans"
line2 = "a  ATCC 6538,     ATCC 9027, Ps. 8739, Ent.     marcescens     brasiliensis   ATCC 10231,"

for line in (line1, line2):
    if line[0] == "D":
        list = []
        for s in line.split():
            if "." in s:
                list.append(s)
            elif list:
                list[-1] = f"{list[-1]} {s}"
        print(list)

    if line[0] == "a":
        count = 0
        list = []
        for s in line2[3:]:
            if count % 15 == 0 or count == 0:
                list.append(s)
                if len(list) > 1: list[-2] = list[-2].rstrip()
            else:
                list[-1] = f"{list[-1]}{s}"
            count += 1
        print(list)
```

output:

```
['Staph. aureus', 'Ps. aeruginosa', 'E. coli ATCC', 'Ser.', 'Asp.', 'Cand. albicans']
['ATCC 6538,', 'ATCC 9027, Ps.', '8739, Ent.', 'marcescens', 'brasiliensis', 'ATCC 10231,']
```

Looks pretty horrible, but hopefully gives some ideas. :)

Comment: Tha's a very good idea and I guess the solution is in this direction. but when you try this on the second line it gives: ['Ps. 8739,', 'Ent. marcescens brasiliensis ATCC 10231,'] because it just puts something with a ".". can you explain the " f"{list[-1]} {s}"?

Comment: The f is to enable string interpolation ( the {s} being replaced with the value of the variable s in the string).

list[-1] is shorthand for "the value in the last index of list"

So the whole thing takes what's in the last index of list, appends it with the string s and replaces the value in the last index of list with the resulting string.

Comment: Do the first characters in front of each example row bear any significance ("D" and "a") that we could use? Is the second row comma delimited? There doesn't seem to be tabs, only spaces... any chance the tabs got lost while pasting the text here?

Comment: Edited my original answer to cover the other example row. Unfortunately I wasn't able to come up with a universal solution as there is not a clear delimiting character.

Comment: Thank you! that is the problem here, there's no character that defines the end of the cell, just the fact that the maximum length is 15, and that if it cuts a word, it should look for the previous empty space.